# How to call the setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, settimeout

I am being given the below mentioned code and asked to print the console after 3 seconds - B and C after A.

I tried

```
  setTimeout(main(),3000);
```

But I get no output.

```
function sleep(){

}

function main(){

console.log('A');

// call after 3 sec
console.log('B');


// call after 3 sec
console.log('C');

}
}
```

Comment: _"But I get no output"_ - That's not possible with the script shown (if we ignore the last `}` that shouldn't be there)

Comment: Good dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above output could also be reproduced using async-await:

```js
function sleep(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("");
    }, time);
  });
}

async function main() {
  await sleep(0);
  console.log('A');

  // call after 3 sec
  await sleep(3000);
  console.log('B');

  // call after 3 sec
  await sleep(3000);
  console.log('C');

}
main();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(main , 3000);
```

remove function call '( )'

How setTimeout works:
You specify the **function** (as a first argument) to be called after your timeout (second argument: 3000)

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should pass the function by name to the `setTimeout` function without calling it.

`setTimeout(main,3000);`

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout(main(), 3000)` will execute main immediately because you put the `()` after it. Just use the name. `setTimeout(main, 3000)`

Also, you'll want to put your timeout on the two specific log statements you want to call later, not the whole function, or you could also log A outside of the main function and then call the main function after the timeout.

```js
function main() {

  console.log('A');

  // call after 3 sec
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('B');
    console.log('C');
  }, 3000);

}

main();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function in the first parameter of `setTimeout`. It is supposed to be a *callback function*(function definition). Just copy the code of the main function inside the `setTimeout` function and it will work.

The `setTimeout` Function is used usually with two parameters.

1. The callback function
2. Time in milliseconds

The *callback function* is called after a given time (second param).

This is how it is called:

```
const callbackFunction = () =>{
   console.log("Inside callback");
}

setTimeout(callbackFunction, 2000);
```

OR simply

```
setTimeout(() =>{
   console.log("Inside callback");
}, 2000);
```

Output (after 2 secs)

```
Inside callback
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    setTimeout(main,3000);

  function main(a){
  
      console.log('A');
  
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log('B'); 

        setTimeout(function(){ 
          console.log('C'); 
        }, 3000);

      }, 3000);
   
  }
```